# Get id of div in nested HTML elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get, using jquery, the `id` of the  first div with class: `post` (367), in the following HTML code:

```
<div id="own-posts">
  <span class="title">Me</span>    
  <div class="posts_container">
    <div class="post"></div>  

    <div id="367" class="post"></div>
    <div id="365" class="post"></div>
    <div id="345" class="post"></div>
    <div id="343" class="post"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Among the solutions I tried:

```
$('#own-posts').children()[1].children()[1].attr('id');
```

Comment: It is not valid to have an ID starting with a number (except in HTML5), older browser may complain of problems.

Comment: @Kolink Thank you for your important remark, I will take it into consideration in future. What about having number in data-attribute, is it causing the same problem?

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces No, it's not! Following Kolink's comment, even it's completly valid to start ID with a number in HTML5, CSS still doesn't like it. So you should follow Kolink's advice

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces I like to use `data-id` when I'm storing an ID number. In jQuery you can access it with `.data("id")` if you want (I don't use jQuery myself, so I just use `.getAttribute("data-id")`)

Comment: @A.Wolff: If I understand you well, it is better to use `data-id` as attribute and start it with a letter, then create further jquery code that will retrieve the id (the number)?

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces you should prefix IDs if using ID attribute, you shouldn't have to prefix IDs if using data-id attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `.post` element doesn't have an ID, so I guess you mean the first `.post` element that actually has an ID attribute :

```
var id = $('#own-posts .post[id]:first').prop('id');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GAV75/)

Comment: +1, It is perfectly working in Fiddle, but I dont know why in my webpage it doesnt work, I should deeply understand your solution.

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the ID `#own-posts`, did you include jQuery and a document ready function etc ?

Comment: I have one element with id #own-posts, jquery and document ready are here, the probmel was that the first child with class `post` didnt have the id, so I used Sergio remark and it works now.Thank you very much for your invaluable hel

Comment: Did you read my answer at all, this selects the first .post element that has an ID?

Comment: I am very sorry I got too many ansewers and comments that I thought you didn't notice that remark.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces this is exactly the purpose of this answer, get first element with class '.post' which has an attribute ID

Comment: @A.Wolff, Totally agreeing with you

Answer (score 1):

`$('#own-posts .post:first').prop('id');` works if all divs with that class have a id.

Otherwise if the pattern is the first `div.post` does not have id, but the second does you can use:

`$('#own-posts .post').eq(1).prop('id');`

I used `.prop()` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: The link is interesting, I will try to understand this and make it work, thank you for your time

Comment: Perfect, the second solution works, it was smart from you to observe that the first div doesnt contain id. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#own-posts .post').eq(1).prop('id');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/GAV75/1/)